# Is there a way to have SBT dependencies exported by default in IntelliJ IDEA module?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have two Scala projects in an IntelliJ IDEA workspace. Project A is an SBT project, and Project B is a non-SBT project which depends on project A via IDEA settings. By default the SBT dependencies of project A are only exported if they are scoped `test`, and if I want to make the `compile` dependencies of project A available to project B, I need to manually check each of the `export` checkboxes in the module dependencies tab, and this resets whenever the project is rebuilt. Is there a way to have the `compile` SBT dependencies exported by default via SBT configuration?